# Transfer big table from stata to Latex

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

I am a new user in this forum so forgive ex-ante my mistakes.

The story is: I have create a big table in Stata (in LaTeX environment it is approximately 3 pages) and when I try to fit it in LaTeX, then I get only one page with as much information as it fits. I have tried to break the table into three parts but the results are not so good.

Is there any command for my problem?

Example:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]

  \raggedleft
\splittablecaption*{Descriptive statistics by country} \label{tab:descriptive stat 1}

\begin{tiny}
\begin{tabular}{rcccccc}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Country} & \textbf{Expenses} & \textbf{Earning assets} & \textbf{Price of deposits} & \textbf{Price of labour} & \textbf{Price of physical capital} & \textbf{Bank profits} \\
    \midrule

Afghanistan & 8.22  & 10.27 & 0.03  & 0.02  & 1.83  & 908.05 \\    
Albania & 8.71  & 11.40 & 0.04  & 0.01  & 0.87  & 3723.46 \\
Algeria & 7.35  & 10.42 & 0.04  & 0.01  & 0.75  & 1184.20 \\
Andorra & 10.45 & 13.66 & 0.03  & 0.01  & 0.39  & 24572.85 \\

UNTIL

Zambia & 7.53  & 9.47  & 0.05  & 0.05  & 2.10  & 427.15 \\

Zimbabwe & 9.54  & 11.28 & 0.04  & 0.04  & 0.83  & 4862.60 \
```

Thank you a priori.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please when posting code always post complete documents including `\documentclass` and `\usepackage` ao we know which packages are being used. I recognise some `booktabs` commands but not the caption commands you use.

It sounds like you want a mult-page table format so `longtable` or `supertab` are the classic choices or newer versions such as `tabu`. I'll show `longtable` as it is part of the standard LaTeX distribution, and I know something about it.

add `\usepackage{longtable}` and replace

```
\begin{table}[htbp]

  \raggedleft
\splittablecaption*{Descriptive statistics by country} \label{tab:descriptive stat 1}

\begin{tiny}
\begin{tabular}{rcccccc}
   \toprule
    \textbf{Country} & \textbf{Expenses} & \textbf{Earning assets} & \textbf{Price of deposits} & \textbf{Price of labour} & \textbf{Price of physical capital} & \textbf{Bank profits} \\
    \midrule
```

by

```
\begin{longtable}{rcccccc}
\caption{Descriptive statistics by country} \label{tab:descriptive stat 1}\\
       \toprule
        \textbf{Country} & \textbf{Expenses} & \textbf{Earning assets} & \textbf{Price of deposits} & \textbf{Price of labour} & \textbf{Price of physical capital} & \textbf{Bank profits} \\
        \midrule
```

and replace

```
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

by

```
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: @DavidCarlise thank you very much for your advice.